# How to solve TypeScript error in React.Children when using child.type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-children

In below React TypeScript component, TypeScript is complaining at `child.type`?

> Argument of type 'string | JSXElementConstructor' is not
> assignable to parameter of type '(({ src, alt }: CardImageProps)
> => Element) | (({ children }: CardBodyProps) => Element)'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(({ src, alt }:
> CardImageProps) => Element) | (({ children }: CardBodyProps) =>
> Element)'.

How to fix this TypeScript error?

```
const Card = ({ children }:CardProps) => {

  const allowed = [CardImage, CardBody];

  return (
    <div
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (!allowed.includes(child.type)) return;
        return child;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

Card.Image = CardImage;
Card.Body = CardBody;

export default Card;
```

Comment: Both `CardBody` and `CardImage` are React components, which means they are functions, and I wouldn't expect them to have a type property on them.

Comment: TypeScript types only exist for the developer experience and only JavaScript data types exist at runtime. Using TypeScript types in the allowed array isn't something you can check at runtime.

Comment: Error explained: TypeScript infers the type of the allowed array and the error complains that child.type is a string, which is not comparable to the types in the array. Both CardImage and CardBody seem to be React components which are functions that return JSX elements.

Comment: @RobertRendell ok and how can I solve this issue? Do I need another approach?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing is because of the signature of the `Array.prototype.includes` method. Given that your `allowed` array is of type `JSXElementConstructor[]` and `child.type` is a `string | JSXElementConstructor`, you cannot compare a `string` and a `JSXElementConstructor`.

---

There's some issues with your approach however:

1. `child` might be `undefined` or `null` and you're directly accessing `child.type`.
2. `child.type` might be a string (for in-built HTML tags) or a function for custom components, or even `undefined` for simple text.

---

How about filtering your `children` like this?

```
const allowed: React.JSXElementConstructor<any>[] = [CardImage, CardBody];
const filteredChildren = React.Children.toArray(children).filter((child) => {
  return (
    React.isValidElement(child) &&
    typeof child.type !== "string" &&
    allowed.includes(child.type)
  );
});
```

This way you make sure that your `child` is indeed a `ReactElement`, it is not a built-in HTML component, and that it is one of either of your allowed components.

> In the CodeSandbox, for some reason, `Array.prototype.includes` doesn't seem to be defined. You can still use: `allowed.indexOf(child.type) >= 0` instead of `allowed.includes(child.type)`

---

With this in mind, if you were to render something like:

```
<Card>
  <CardImage src="https://placeholder.com/150" />
  <CardBody>Card Text</CardBody>
  Text that won't be in card.
  <ComponentThatShouldNotBeInCard />
</Card>
```

Only `CardImage` and `CardBody` will be rendered.

---

You can check out the following CodeSandbox to help you out:

[image: Edit React Children Filtering]

Comment: Trying your example I get this TypeScript error:
`Type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.`

Comment: What line gives you that issue?

Comment: line 29 on `child.type`

Comment: I am using ` "react": "^17.0.2",`  and `"typescript": "~5.3",`, but I cannot get this reproducible in a sandbox?

Comment: You don't see that, because on line 29 you get on `.includes` method this error:
`Property 'includes' does not exist on type '((({ src }: CardImageProps) => Element) | (({ children }: CardBody) => Element))[]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2016' or later.typescript`

Comment: You're right, I added a note regarding the `includes`. I also realized I missed the typing for the `allowed` array which should be of `React.JSXElementConstructor<any>[]`. That way the `includes` (or `indexOf`) should work.